# InvalidArgumentException View [login] not found

Tags: php, laravel, adminlte

I cannot access my login form on localhost getting this error and I really don't know where to look more for some setting issue which can cause the problem.

I mentioned that on-line the website and form is running just fine but localhost

The error is keep telling me that:
**View [login] not found. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\cicobella\resources\views\auth\login.blade.php)**

**login was not found.
Are you sure the view exists and is a .blade.php file?**

But I have checked and the file is present in there having this code line1:  @extends('adminlte::login')

.env is created website everything is functional but the login form

Please any help. Thank you in advance

[route list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oyyJI.jpg)

Comment: what is the output of `php artisan route:list` ? Probably it's because you installed adminltde, but didn't registered your routes

Comment: @SamuelAialaFerreira I have added the route list output in my asking form up. However I cannot see nothing wrong in the routes and this is happening just local on the hosting everything is running just fine... Any thoughts?

Comment: are you caching your routes ? `php artisan route:clear`

Comment: @SamuelAialaFerreira I did all those steps following I think all stackoverflow posts related too... route, cache, etc.... :|

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, I found the solution here:
https://www.tutorialfor.com/questions-304299.htm

Try using:
@extends('adminlte::auth.login')

Instead of:
@extends('adminlte::login')

This worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

Hi all I was able to fix this seems that the github clone was corrupted, once I backed up my website and replace all files everything came back to normal